# Mac OS X asks for Admin Username and Password twice before allowing access to Cisco AnyConnect VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, passwords, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

OS X asks me -- twice -- to enter my admin username and password before it will let me connect to Cisco AnyConnect VPN.  This is annoying and unnecessary.

Text of the prompt:

> OS X wants to make changes.  Type an administrator's name and password to allow this.
>
> OS X wants to use the "System" keychain.

[image: OS X wants to make changes]

How can I configure the keychain to allow Cisco VPN access without prompting unnecessarily?

Comment: How do I block this request that I get (3 times) before it gets to the correct cert on the smartcard?

Answer (score 39):

Found the answer on a [Google Groups forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/macenterprise/Z89i2ZaReV8/2yCMT3ADBgAJ):

> • Launch /Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access
>
> • Select "System" from the Keychains menu in the upper left
>
> • Select "Certificates" from the Category menu in the lower left
>
> • Find the entry that corelates to your computer's name in the list on the right, and click on the disclosure triangle.
>
> • Secondary click on the "Private Key" entry that appears and select "Get Info" from the contextual menu that appears.
>
> • Select the Access Control tab.
>
> • You can then *either* add AnyConnect to the the list at the bottom of the screen (more secure, but you will need to repeat this process anytime the version of AnyConnect changes), *or* toggle the radio button to "Allow all applications to access this item".

A similar answer [shows a picture but provides fewer instructions](https://superuser.com/a/1070277/280734)

Comment: I've looking for this answer for ages! Thanks 

Comment: This was very useful in pointing me to the right spot; however, for others who may be getting here, the "entry that correlates to your computer's name" was not what worked for me: in my case, adding AnyConnect to the `localhost` entry did not fix the issue; what did, was adding it to a seeming "random hex" entry.

Comment: For me, on two computers, the causative item was under "login" (instead of "System").  Removing the item solved the problem.  In both cases it appeared that AnyConnect was trying to access a private key it didn't need.  Anyways, thanks for the instructions!

Comment: I was able to give permission to the app but even after saving, the access control list got reset. "Allow all applications to access this item" also didn't work...any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you! My first thought was to transfer from System to login keychains but this makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked out

Comment: @rramakrishnaa Getting the same thing here. Did you ever sort it out?

Comment: Yes @Travis it got fixed by upgrading to the latest version of MacOS

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem for sometime and none of the suggestions worked. What did work for me was changing the VPN profile (your sys admin will need to do this for you as its a server side profile that gets downloaded when you connect).

The setting that made the difference was CertificateStoreMac, the default seems to be All which causes AnyConnect to try to look in the system keychain. If you change this to Login it'll stop doing that and stop these login prompts. Your certificates for the server should be installed in the login keychain as thats what happens with current AnyConnect versions when you go through VPN enrolment and download the certs and use the OTP creds.